# How to Map two List Of type String in third List of Object

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert two List of String type into List of Person

first List contain the firstname of person and 2nd list contain lastname
which i want to map in List of Person Object

```
class Person {

    private String fistName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String fistName, String lastName) {
        this.setFirstName(fistName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
    }
}


public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> firstname=new ArrayList<String>();
           firstname.add("Laxmi");
           firstname.add("kaya");
           firstname.add("sapna");

           List<String> lastname=new ArrayList<String>();
           lastname.add("P");
           lastname.add("K");
           lastname.add("S");
           List<Person> emp = Stream.of(firstname,lastname).forEach(e-> new Person(e.get(0),e.get(1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using an `IntStream` and read both lists while traversing it.

Comment: are they the same sizes always? this is the crucial point... and if not, you should explain how to treat that case...

Comment: Yes they will be same size

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
List<Person> res = IntStream.range(0, firstName.size())
                            .mapToObj(i -> new Person(firstName.get(i), lastName.get(i)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However this is assuming both `List`'s are the same size

This solution uses [`IntStream::range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to generate a Stream of indices for the two `List`'s

Comment: It's not Exact solution but your code help me to get Exact solution,Thank a lot to you

Comment: This is the solution--->                                                                                              List<Person> person = IntStream.range(0, firstName.size()) .mapToObj(i -> new Person(firstName.get(i),lastName.get(i))).collect(Collectors.toList());